# Multiple SpartContexts run on same JVM

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark, and got such an error which stop the whole spark process:

```
16:01:37.289 [main] WARN  org.apache.spark.SparkContext - Another SparkContext is being 
constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since 
only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext 
was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
```

I don't think I have multiple `SparkContext` running on the same JVM. How to check this? Or force kill the one already running?

Comment: Can you post more of the stacktrace?  The full stacktrace logged in this warning message should include the call site of the existing SparkContext.

Comment: Is possible then you have take a test and don't have stop the spark context, in the next test a context maybe opened.

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to instantiate another SparkContext in the same JVM which already have a SparkContext initiated,SparkContext constructor will throw an exception. You can turn the exception off with spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts=true.

```
//SparkConf which is using to instantiate SparkContext (new SparkContext((conf))
conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true")
```

Normally spark will open 4040 port in the running machine if you are starting it in local mode. You can run one port scan from 4040 to 4050 and check the process names.

Comment: Explanations are the difference between good answers and suboptimal answers.

Comment: Thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no list of active contexts for you to query. As @[Devan M S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2846171/devan-m-s) points out, you can disable the throwing of exceptions with `conf.set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts","true")`, however **Spark will still issue a warning and with good reason**. Spark make use of JVM-wide caches (see [SPARK-2243](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2243)).

Spark does not provide an API to kill of the existing context either (given they assume it is a singleton this is a little odd, but hey). As @[Josh Rosen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590203/josh-rosen) said in the comments, you can find where the new context is being created via the full stack trace.

The answer for your particular problem depends on when you are encountering it. If it is during automated testing, then as [faster2b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2243805/faster2b) states it could be a test is not clearing up after itself. I'd recommend using a [JUnit Rule](https://github.com/mlk/AssortmentOfJUnitRules) to handle the clean up.

If it is during runtime then I'd look at using a [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), so only one part of the application is responsible for creating the Spark Context.